# azure attach read only disk

Tags: azure, diskmanagement, forensics

i am running forensic experiment on azure and need to use one machine for the experiment and a different machine for the looking at the content. the experiments rely on registry and other elements and i am worried as soon as i attached the new host will corrupt it. is there option to make it readonly and still attached it to the new machine? this is operating system that i want ot attach. one machine must be windows, the machine for looking at content can be linux or windows doesn't matter (but not mac as is on azure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't attach the disk as read only to the VM itself in Azure, however you can configure it as read only in whatever operating system you are mounting it in using the standard configuration options for that OS.

You could also create a snapshot of the disk before you mount it so you can revert back if needed.